# How to compare my model's performance with that of others?

Tags: machine-learning, model, model-evaluation, method-comparison

I'm building an audio classifier and would like to compare my model's performance with that of others. I use the [Urban Sound Dataset](https://serv.cusp.nyu.edu/projects/urbansounddataset/urbansound8k.html). I searched for already existing results on this dataset but couldn't find much.

I can see myself facing this problem in future projects too (and I might not be alone) which is why I'm asking for someone more experienced to share his approach to finding already existing results on some public dataset.

What is your approach for comparing your model's performance with that of others on some public dataset?

Comment: What are you predicting and with what type of model? What are your inputs, outputs and method? This will help others determine how you may compare. If there is a standard for comparison, you should discover it.

Comment: @Todd It's an audio classifier for the mentioned UrbanSound8K dataset--given an audio recording of some urban sound (siren, drilling, etc), the model predicts the urban sound. Input to my model are the features I extracted from the audio recordings (melspectrogram, mfcc, chorma-stft, spectral_contrast, tonnetz). Output is one of the 10 possible classes, each representing a different urban sound.

Comment: @Todd What do you mean with "if there is a standard for comparison, you should discover it"?

Comment: I would try looking for research papers that solve similar problems to yours. It probably won't give you a 1:1 comparison, that can probably only be achieved by using the same data. Like the ImageNet challenges. Those comparisons are apples to apples because the data and the problem are the same.  Anyways, look for publications on similar problems as those often report the rate of error, etc. That should give you an idea, at least.

Comment: Here's an example, average accuracy ~70%: https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/apsipa-transactions-on-signal-and-information-processing/article/environmental-sound-recognition-a-survey/96211C365DC7B250CEEFFB15026A5CDF/core-reader